# If every finitely generated subgroup of a linear group G is solvable, then G is solvable

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups, solvable-groups, linear-groups, derived-subgroup

I've been working on this question for a long time now and I still have no idea how to approach it. I tried induction on the dimension of the matrices in G but can't complete the induction step. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I expect this follows from the fact that the derived length of a solvable linear group of degree $n$ is bounded in terms of $n$ - I believe it is $O(\log n)$.

Comment: The derived length of a solvable group $G<GL(n,F)$  is bounded by a real-valued function $f(n)$. This is theorem Zassenhaus, Beweis eines Satzes fiber diskrete Gruppen. Abh. Math. Sem. Univ. Hamburg 12, 289-312 (1938).

Comment: @DietrichBurde The question has no additional information but I think F can be assumed to have characteristic zero since this was stated at the beginning of the relevant chapter in the lecture notes. The Mal‘cev and zassenhaus theorems are familiar to me.

Comment: @kabenyuk I assume we can use this bound on the subgroups but I don’t see how this bound is of any help :(

Comment: For example, suppose the derived length is at most 2, then $[[x,y],[u,v]]=e$ for any $x,y,u,v\in G$, since the group generated by four elements of $\operatorname{gr}(x,y,u,v)$ has the derived length at most 2.

Comment: @kabenyuk Now I understand! So in particular this same bound applies to the total group by considering the commutators of each selection of elements individually. Thank you so much for your help.