# If every finite quotient group of a finitely generated linear group G is solvable, then G is solvable

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated, infinite-groups, solvable-groups, linear-groups

For this question, I was able to show that each finite quotient is polycyclic: Suppose $N$ is a normal subgroup of finite index. Then, all subgroups of $G/N$ are finite, so $G/N$ is Noetherian. A solvable group is polycyclic iff it is Noetherian. At this point, I don't know how to continue or if I'm even going in the right direction. I am familiar with Theorems by Mal'cev, Milnor, Wolf etc.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: See [your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4356631/if-every-finitely-generated-subgroup-of-a-linear-group-g-is-solvable-then-g-is) from yesterday.  We have again Zassenhaus' Lemma (what you wrote), "On Linear Noetherian Groups", Lemma $2$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde But does Zassenhaus' lemma apply also to finite solvable quotients of linear groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G \leq \mathrm{GL}_n(K)$ be your group. Let $f(n)$ be the maximal derived length of a soluble subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n(F)$ for any field $F$ (Zassenhaus's theorem). Suppose $g \in G^{(f(n))}$ is nontrivial. By Mal'cev's theorem, there is a finite field $F$ and a homomorphism $\pi : G \to \mathrm{GL}_n(F)$ such that $\pi(g) \neq 1$. But $\pi(g) \in \pi(G)^{(f(n))}$, and $\pi(G)$ is finite and therefore soluble by hypothesis, so this is a contradiction. Hence $G^{(f(n))} = 1$.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!

Comment: One more question: from my understanding, Mal'cev's Theorem allows us to conclude that $G$ is residually finite. Hence, for the above $g$, there exists a finite-index normal subgroup $N \triangleleft G$ such that the projection $\pi : G \to G/N$ satisfies $\pi(g) \neq 1$. How can we conclude that $G/N$ is (isomorphic to) $GL_n(F)$ for some finite field F, in order to use the bound $f(n)$?

Comment: It's not normally included in the statement, but look at the proof. That's how it's proved.